# What is the ticker symbol for "Vanguard Target Retirement 2045 Trust Plus"?

Tags: 401k, target-date-fund

Hi I'm offered this plan through work but i can't find a ticker for it so that i can compare it to something else using tools like google finance.

All I find is "Vanguard Target Retirement 2045 Fund" and "Vanguard Target Retirement 2045 Inv Fund" both pointing to VTIVX. Is it the same thing as "Trust Plus" or is my employer has some custom thing built just for them?

You can see "Trust Plus" page here but it doesn't have a ticker 
https://institutional.vanguard.com/VGApp/iip/site/institutional/investments/productoverview?fundId=1658

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use VTIVX.

The "Target Retirement 2045" and "Target Retirement 2045 Trust Plus" are the same underlying fund, but the latter is offered through employers.  The only differences I see are the expense ratio and the minimum investment dollars.  But for the purposes of comparing funds, it should be pretty close.

Here is the [list of all of Vanguard's target retirement funds.](https://institutional.vanguard.com/VGApp/iip/institutional/csa/investments/aggregateviews/multiAsset?sac=tarDate)

Also, note that the "Trust Plus" hasn't been around as long, so you don't see the returns beyond the last few years.  That's another reason to use plain VTIVX for comparison.

See also: [Why doesn't a mutual fund in my 401(k) have a ticker symbol?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22050)

Comment: thanks, I also noticed the diff in the expense ratio. Vanguard website shows 0.18% while my employer's Fidelity website shows 0.06%. Does that sound correct? I guess big companies can get a better rate?

Comment: Yes.  So that means you will get 0.06% better returns than the ticker symbol for VTIVX shows.